# Access declared "try-with"-resource in catch-clause

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I have an autoclosable class named "VirtuellTx". It is a special kind of transaction and supports a "commit()"- and "rollback()"-Method. How can I access the declared "VirtuellTx"-resource in the catch-block to perform a rollback()?

```
try (VirtuellTx lVtx = new VirtuellTx()) {
    // do something ...
    lVtx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    lVtx.rollback();
}
```

The catch-block can not access lVtx: "lVtx cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources are only in scope inside the block of the try-with-resources statement. [JLS says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a variable declared in the ResourceSpecification of a try-with-resources statement (§14.20.3) is from the declaration rightward over the remainder of the ResourceSpecification and the entire try block associated with the try-with-resources statement.

Move the `catch` inside:

```
try (VirtuellTx lVtx = new VirtuellTx()) {
  try {
    // do something ...
    lVTX.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    lVtx.rollback();
  }
}
```